# Ubuntu won't use Nvidia Drivers for MX 150. (Black Screen)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I am really at my wits ends with this problem. I simply cannot find a way to get by laptop to use the MX150 instead of the integrated intel GPU. I have tried everything I can find.

Firstly I tried to simply install the latest Nvidia driver from `Software & Updates`. When I rebooted, there was no change. Then I tried to install drivers from the terminal using `ubuntu-drivers` but to no avail.

I was originally using Wayland but after some reading, I found that it doesn't play nice with Nvidia GPUs and after some hassle, I switched over to X11.

I tried to then reinstall the Nvidia driver in the same manner but when I came to reboot my computer, I was greeted by a black screen. The only way I was able to recover from this state was to boot in recovery mode and as root, use `apt purge nvidia*` and `apt autoremove`. When this happened, if I waited for long enough I could use `Ctrl+Alt+F<x>` to switch to `tty<x>`. I also tried to run `sudo startx` from `tty2` but this cause it to become completely black and unresponsive.

Additionally, I have turned SecureBoot off from the BIOS and I have also tried all the different driver versions aside from the recommend version 440.

When I did manage to get the computer to boot, Nvidia X Settings just opened with an empty menu. I tried to use `prime-select` to change back to Intel, reboot and then back to Nvidia, but nothing worked.

I really cannot find anything else to try on the internet and much as I love Ubuntu this might be a dealbreaker since I need my GPU for machine learning.

Here are the outputs from a number of useful commands (please comment if I have missed anything which you feel might be important):

1. `inxi -G`

```
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Device 3ea0
           Card-2: NVIDIA GP108M [GeForce MX150]
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) driver: i915
           Resolution: 1920x1080@59.93hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics (Whiskey Lake 3x8 GT2)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 19.0.8
```

2. `glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"`

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) UHD Graphics (Whiskey Lake 3x8 GT2)
```

3. `lspci -nnk |egrep -A3 -i "3D|VGA"`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3ea0]
    Subsystem: Razer USA Ltd. Device [1a58:1000]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
02:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] [10de:1d10] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Razer USA Ltd. GP108M [GeForce MX150] [1a58:1000]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia
03:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] [8086:15da] (rev 02)
```

4. `cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 435.21


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce MX150"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "31"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

5. `cat /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf`

```
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
```

I really hope someone can help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Dear @turbo_sheep, thanks for your question, I have exactly the same problem and exactly the same laptop. Could you solve your problem?